# How to write long equations inside piecewise function with same equation number

Tags: math-mode, arrays, cases

I am facing trouble while writing the long equation inside the piecewise function with same equation number ,the latex code i am using is

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,asymmetric]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}


\begin{numcases}
dododododdoodododdodo\\
gogogogogogogogogogogog\\
dhchdschdshgshdghd\\
dgcfsdgfcdsgfhgsdf

\label{positive}
 \label{negative}
 \end{numcases}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

I want that `dododododododod` and `gogogogogogog` under same equation  number i.e (0.1), i have tried the `\begin{equation}` buts looks like this does not work in the given environment,

Edit : Because of long equations I have to use `\\`  after some part of equation, which I have represented here by
`dododododod\\ gogogogoggo`

Please Help,
Thankyou.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thankyou @Mensch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `numcases` for the job at hand. Instead, use a `cases` environment inside an ordinary `equation` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays

%% math stuff:
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'cases' environment
%%\usepackage{amsfonts} % is loaded automatically by amssymb
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cases}      % for 'numcases' environment
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

%% other stuff:
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,asymmetric]{geometry}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2} % just for ths example

\begin{equation}\label{positive} % use only one \label directive per equation environment
\begin{cases}
  dododododdoodododdodo\\
  gogogogogogogogogogogog\\
  dhchdschdshgshdghd\\
  dgcfsdgfcdsgfhgsdf
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up request: To typeset two separately-numbered two-line equations, I suggest you do something like this:

```
\begin{numcases}
\mbox{$\begin{aligned} 
  &dododododdoodododdodo \\ 
  &gogogogogogogogogogogog 
\end{aligned}$} \label{positive} \\[1ex]
\mbox{$\begin{aligned} 
  &dhchdschdshgshdghd \\ 
  &dgcfsdgfcdsgfhgsdf 
\end{aligned}$} \label{negative}
\end{numcases}
```

LaTeX will issue a bunch of warning messages but will, if you step through them (or just type "r" for "run"), eventually produce the desired result. I'm afraid I have no idea how to suppress these immaterial warning messages.

Comment: Thankyou @Mico for your response, when i run this latex code, this only showing whole function with equation number 2.1, but i want ```dodododod``` and ```gogogogog``` as equation 0.1 (or any other number ), along with ```dhchdschdchgshdghd``` and ```dgcfsd,,``` as equation number 0.2 (or any other number ), so basically i want to collect first two and the last two under different equation numbers.

Comment: @TheStudent - Please see the addendum I posted.

Comment: Thankyou Soo much @Mico, it worked.